# Подключение клиента к моему серверу на другом компьютере

Tags: сервер, сеть, client

Я делаю мультиплеерную игру, имеется клиент и сервер. Я хочу протестировать игру со своим другом не на локальной сети и не хочу арендовать хост. Пробовал через хамачи, но у моего друга не произошло подключение, когда я смог подключиться, по ip hamachi. Знаю что можно это сделать через открытие портов, погуглил эту тему узнал что нужен белый ip у провайдера покупать. Я хочу просто запустить сервак и протестировать работу игры, поэтому мне не желательны денежные затраты на это. Есть какие-нибудь удобные программы для этого, в крайнем случаи статьи тоже подойдут.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала зайди в настройки роутера. Посмотри адрес подключения Интернет... Если начинается с 100,10,172.16-32,192.168 то проброс не поможет. Если же адрес белый и совпадает с там что показывает yandex.ru/internet то задайте вопрос с указанием модели вашего роутера или посмотрите в поиске 'модель роутера проброс портов'.